# How to know the column name from a table based on the column values

Tags: sql, informix

I am working in Informix and I want to know if there is a simple way to know the tabname/colname by its possible column values.

For example:

```
table1

Register 1
==========
id        1
col1      3
col2      Y

Register 2
==========
id       2
col1     43
col2     X 

Register 3
==========
id       2
col1     0
col2     Z 

Register 4
==========
id       2
col1     23
col2     F 


table2

Register 1
==========
id        1
col1      X
col2      Y

Register 2
==========
id       2
col1     X
col2     X 

Register 3
==========
id       2
col1     Z
col2     Z 

Register 4
==========
id       2
col1     X
col2     X 


table3

Register 1
==========
id       1
col1   ASX
```

With this database, if I want to know the colnames and their related tabnames of the database that contain X, Y and Z (amoung other values).

It could be something like this:

```
select tabname, colname 
where ('X','Y','Z') in colnamevalues --this has been invented by me
```

And this should return the following values:

```
table1.col2 
table2.col1
table2.col2

--Note that the columns fetched contains also other values 
--different from 'X', 'Y' and 'Z' but T didn't fix in this case 
--the whole list of values, only some of them
```

I have queried for other Q&A but all of them look to use some functions of other databases such as Oracle or SQL Server and I don't understand them very well.

Comment: This may not be achievable.

Comment: :( even with a procedure or something like that?

Comment: You could try selecting all the table and column names from the system tables, then loop through them to see where your value is stored.  It certainly wouldn't be simple.

Comment: Ok I'll try. I know colname and tabname as the names for columns and tables names respectively but I don't know how to join those with the values of the columns... Could you please provide me an example??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all the tables that exist on a database by querying the [systables](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqlr.doc/ids_sqr_072.htm?lang=en):

```
SELECT  tabname
FROM    systables
WHERE   tabtype = 'T'   --get only tables
        AND tabid > 99; --skip catalog tables
```

You can join it to the [syscolumns](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqlr.doc/ids_sqr_025.htm?lang=en) table to get the columns:

```
SELECT  t.tabname, c.colname
FROM    systables t
    INNER JOIN syscolumns c ON (c.tabid = t.tabid)
WHERE   t.tabtype = 'T' AND t.tabid > 99;
```

And if you know the type of values you can even filter it. Example if you're looking for "strings":

```
SELECT  t.tabname, c.colname
FROM    systables t
    INNER JOIN syscolumns c ON (c.tabid = t.tabid)
WHERE   t.tabtype = 'T' AND t.tabid > 99
        AND MOD(c.coltype,256) IN (
            0,  --CHAR
            13, --VARCHAR
            15, --NCHAR
            16, --NVARCHAR
            40, --LVARCHAR
            43  --LVARCHAR
        );
```

The next example works, but it really should be optimized and bullet proof, but can get you kick off.

When I have time I get another look at it and check what can be optimized and put some error handling.

Another way to do it is scripting, what **OS** are you running?

Schema creation:

```
CREATE TABLE tab1(
    id      INT,
    col1    CHAR(3),
    col2    CHAR(3)
);

INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES (1, 3, 'Y');
INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES (2, 43, 'X');
INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES (2, 0, 'Z');
INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES (2, 23, 'F');

CREATE TABLE tab2(
    id      INT,
    col1    CHAR(3),
    col2    CHAR(3)
);

INSERT INTO tab2 VALUES (1, 'X', 'Y');
INSERT INTO tab2 VALUES (2, 'X', 'X');
INSERT INTO tab2 VALUES (2, 'Z', 'Z');
INSERT INTO tab2 VALUES (2, 'X', 'X');

CREATE TABLE tab3(
    id      INT,
    col1    CHAR(3)
);

INSERT INTO tab3 VALUES (1, 'ASX');
```

Sample function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_columns()
    RETURNING LVARCHAR(257) AS col;

    DEFINE stmt     VARCHAR(255);
    DEFINE tab_name VARCHAR(128,0);
    DEFINE tab_id   INTEGER;
    DEFINE col_name VARCHAR(128,0);

    DEFINE o_tname VARCHAR(128,0);
    DEFINE o_cname VARCHAR(128,0);

    CREATE TEMP TABLE out_table(
        t_name VARCHAR(128,0),
        c_name VARCHAR(128,0)
    );

    CREATE TEMP TABLE tab_v (
        col1 VARCHAR(255)
    );

    INSERT INTO tab_v VALUES ('X');
    INSERT INTO tab_v VALUES ('Y');
    INSERT INTO tab_v VALUES ('Z');

    FOREACH tables FOR 
        SELECT  tabname, tabid
        INTO    tab_name, tab_id 
        FROM    systables 
        WHERE   tabid > 99 AND tabtype = 'T'

            FOREACH column FOR
                SELECT  colname
                INTO    col_name
                FROM    syscolumns
                WHERE   tabid = tab_id
                        AND MOD(coltype,256) IN (
                            0,  --CHAR
                            13, --VARCHAR
                            15, --NCHAR
                            16, --NVARCHAR
                            40, --LVARCHAR
                            43  --LVARCHAR
                )

                    LET stmt = "INSERT INTO out_table "||
                                "SELECT '"||tab_name||"', '"||col_name||"' "||
                                "FROM "||tab_name||" "||
                                "WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tab_v v WHERE v.col1 = "||col_name||");";

                    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt;
            END FOREACH
    END FOREACH

    FOREACH out FOR
        SELECT  UNIQUE t_name, c_name
        INTO    o_tname, o_cname
        FROM    out_table
            RETURN o_tname||"."||o_cname WITH RESUME;
    END FOREACH

    DROP TABLE out_table;
    DROP TABLE tab_v;
END FUNCTION;

EXECUTE FUNCTION get_columns();
```

Comment: Thanksssss I'm in Windows, Informix db. The version of Informix is... 12.10 or 11.50, now I'm at home and I can't check it but when I come back to the office on Monday I will be able to, so if you need I will tell you

Comment: The basic outline is good.  The nested FOREACH loops should be a single loop — you can join the two queries into one.  The whole process will be slow in general; it does essentially multiple complete table scans, a few of which might be indexed.  You could, in theory, refine the search so that if the term being searched for is, say, 22 characters long, you ignore the columns which are shorter than 22 characters long (most numeric columns; character columns shorter than 22; etc.)  It would be intriguing to work out whether you can avoid multiple scans on each table.

Comment: The reason for the two loops was to get all the columns and try to write one query per table but time was short and I ran to my daughters ;) I'll give it a shot next Tuesday if you not get to it early.

Comment: Thanks Ricardo, on Monday i'll try with your proposal ;)

Comment: @RicardoHenriques my version is "IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 12.10.FC3IE" and I have checked to paste your "get_columns" in my SQL editor to afterwards, launch it with the "EXECUTE FUNCTION get_columns();" but the console says "   801: SQL Edit buffer is full.". Do I have to paste the function in another place??? Sorry...

Comment: Save it as an sql file and on the dbaccess query menu choose open file or in the same menu choose use editor and paste it afterwards.